# Intercepting all logging messages

Tags: python, logging

I'm working with an application where just about every module and every class emits `logging` messages.

I need a way to capture every single one of those messages without explicitly attaching a handler via `.addHandler()` to each logging instance (which is what I'm doing right now).

Is there any way to attach a handler to *every* logging instance at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging` uses a hierarchy of loggers. Add a handler to the root logger and it will receive logged messages from child loggers, too.

To access the root logger use `logging.getLogger()`.

Comment: Every logger is initialized like this: `logger = logging.getLogger('LoggerNameWithoutPeriods')`. I can't really find a hierarchy in them because they are all top-level.

Comment: @Blender: There's still a root logger. `logging.getLogger()` returns it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to log everything to the standard output you can use the method [logging.basicConfig](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html?highlight=logging.basicconfig#logging.basicConfig) to initialize the logging configuration:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)
```